# List comprehension result differs between Cython and CPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, compatibility

Here is the program I run (after simplification for the sake of demonstration) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
ALPHABET = 'AB'
word='A'
assert not [l for l in word if l not in ALPHABET] , "Failed"
```

I am using Linux/Ubuntu. I have cpython 3.5.

```
Cpython (./demo.py) : no assert, ok.
pypy3 (pypy3 demo.py) : no assert, ok. 
nuitka (nuitka --run --python-version=3.5 demo.py) : no assert, ok.
```

But, for cython:

```sh
cython -3 --embed demo.py
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.5m -O3 -o demo demo.c -lpython3.5m -lm -lutil -ldl
./demo
```

I get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 5, in init demo (demo.c:736)
    assert not [l for l in word if l not in ALPHABET] , "Failed"
AssertionError: Failed
```

Seems the comprehension list, when in the "assert not", is not evaluated as False

=> What am I missing out ???

Comment: If cython claims the list isn't empty, it might be a Good Idea to tell it to show you the list's contents.

Comment: As far as I remember, it says empty. If you push the comprehension list to a variable and then test the variable, it works fine (same as "other" pythons). I just need to understand the behaviour for exaclty THIS code.

Comment: You might get more stable and readable code by using `assert all(l in ALPHABET for l in word), "Failed"`. This may also be faster, since it will stop iterating when it finds the first violation. (It would also help if ALPHABET is a set instead of a string.)

Comment: Just an update to this, the issue I filed was fixed and I believe cython has made a release containing this fix

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in cython, I've reported it on their tracker [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1920)

I've simplified the reproduction to:

```
assert not [l for l in [1] if False], 'FAIL'
```

cython is incorrectly optimizing this to `raise AssertionError('FAIL')` at compile time:

```
  /* "demo.py":2
 * #!/usr/bin/python3
 * assert not [l for l in [1] if False], 'FAIL'             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 */
  #ifndef CYTHON_WITHOUT_ASSERTIONS
  if (unlikely(!Py_OptimizeFlag)) {
    if (unlikely(!0)) {
      PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_AssertionError, __pyx_n_u_FAIL);
      __PYX_ERR(0, 2, __pyx_L1_error)
    }
  }
  #endif
```